# Order by descending aggregation within window function in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions, ranking-functions

I have a dataset that features duplicate values of the the primary variable, something like the following:

```
col1    col2    counts
110    False    1
111    False    2
111    False    1
112    True     3
112    False    2
112    False    1
113    False    1
114    False    1
115    False    2
115    False    1
116    False    1
117    False    1
118    False    4
118    False    3
118    False    2
118    False    1
```

I have achived this by using the following code

```
SELECT DISTINCT ctm_nbr
,col1
,col2
,RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col2) AS counts
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY ctm_nbr, row_numb DESC
```

However, my desired output needs to be ordered such that `counts` is descending yet `col1` remains partitioned, so that I can see, for example, which value from col1 has the highest number of counts. Like this...

```
col1    col2    counts
118    False    4
118    False    3
118    False    2
118    False    1
112    True     3
112    False    2
112    False    1
115    False    2
115    False    1
111    False    2
111    False    1
110    False    1
113    False    1
114    False    1
116    False    1
117    False    1
```

I have tried various iterations of the final `ORDER BY` clause but just can't quite produce the output I need. Guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions in the `order by`.  I think you just want:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ctm_nbr) DESC,
         ctm_nbr,
         row_numb DESC
```

This assumes that the count is the maximum value of `row_numb()`.  So you can also express this as:

```
ORDER BY MAX(row_numb) OVER (PARTITION BY ctm_nbr) DESC,
         ctm_nbr,
         row_numb DESC
```

Comment: Yep, this'll do it. 
For some reason this did not occur to me at all.
Thanks @Gordon Linoff.